# Install wordpress in rails public directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I'm trying to install wordpress in my rails app. I downloaded and configure wordpress in my rails/public directory. I also configured wp.config file mysql info. However, after apache restart app/blog/index.php I don't see wordpress setup page but I get a prompt to download index.php file. I must be missing some step here? Here is my apache file

```
    
    ...
    
        PassengerEnabled Off
        
           RewriteEngine On
           RewriteBase /testme_wordpress/
           RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
           RewriteRule . /testme_wordpress/index.php [L]
         
    
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, you would need to configure apache to execute .php files in that directory. There are a couple ways to do that.

You might run into more problems after doing that, depending on how you've set up your rails deploy on apache. If it's with passenger... I'm not sure passenger is going to play well with this plan.

But... why the heck would you want to do this?  It sounds like not a great idea. What do you have to gain from having a WordPress in a rails app public directory instead of somewhere else not in the middle of a rails app?

Comment: Yes you're are right. Apache can't run PHP without the module.